# What does the cup core usage?

Tags: cpu

It was running web application on my VPC(virtual private cloud) but I got a times for waiting for the page response in 15-20 sec. this page has many query in mysql. but when I looking in htop command I got one cpu usage in one core I don't known this's a normal state or has a problem on my vpc. I have 4 vcpu. If is posible to shared the load in 4 vcpu?.

```
1[###                    ]5%
2[#######################]95%
3[                       ]0%
4[                       ]0%
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which lznguage do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually that means there's a long-running process that's handling all the work for your page. My guess is the database needs some indexes on columns, but with one request, only one CPU will get used like that normally.